# достать словарь из сериализованного json объекта

Tags: python, json, flask

у меня есть функция на python с flask

```
from flask import jsonify
def method1():
    result = {"jsonrpc": "2.0", ... }
    return jsonify(result)
```

далее, из другого метода я вызываю method1:

```
def method2():
    otherResult = method1()
    ...
```

в method2 я хочу достать содержимое result(который из method1). Как мне это сделать?
проблема в том, что если я пытаюсь сделать вот так:

```
response = otherResult['jsonrpc']
```

то при выполнении получается ошибка:

```
TypeError: 'Response' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При вызове `method1` вам возвращается объект Response, который содержит передаваемые данные в виде `bytes`. Чтобы преобразовать эти данные в словарь, вам необходимо их сначала декодировать, а потом преобразовать используя библиотеку json.

Например вот так:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import jsonify
import json
app = Flask(__name__)


def method1():
    result = {"jsonrpc": "2.0"}
    return jsonify(result)


@app.route("/")
def hello():
    response = method1()
    data = response.get_data().decode()
    dct = json.loads(data)
    return dct["jsonrpc"]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: Всё-таки переводить данные в json и потом сразу парсить обратно как-то немножко перебор

Comment: Да, в данном случае избыточно, но кто знает, для чего автор вопроса сделал именно так. Может там логика хитрее, чем видится нам.